# GitHub Pages shows white page

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I'm trying to host an angular app using Github pages. To deploy it, I use the agular-cli-ghpages command `ng build --prod --base-href "m0kova01.github.io/DiscGolfProject/"`. I then run `ngh` and it tells me that it was successfully published. However, when I go to the page to view it, only a blank white page shows up. I've tried clearing the cache and it is still a white page. I've had it work before, but when I push changes, it doesn't update automatically. For this reason, I have to rerun the commands to publish it again.
The errors I'm getting are all `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()`

Could someone help me understand why this is happening, and how I can get it to work?

Comment: I see a site at https://m0kova01.github.io/DiscGolfProject/, is it working now?

Comment: Yes, I got it to work, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what was wrong, but it ended up working by redoing the commands to deploy